# Using a number to quit a program in c++ while not evaluating the actual number

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create a loop that allows a user to input an integer until they quit the program using the number -99. The program is suppose to then print the largest and smallest number to the screen, but it keeps saying that my smallest number is -99.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Initialize integers for use
    long int number, largest, smallest;

    // Set condition for user input 
    while (number != -99)
    {
        // Allow user to input numbers to test 
        cout << " Enter a number to find the smallest and largest integer. " << endl;
        cout << " Enter -99 to quit " << endl;
        cin >> number;


        // Evaluate user input 
        if (number < smallest)
        {
            smallest = number;

        }

        if (number > largest)
        {
            largest = number;
        }
    }

    cout << " The smallest number you entered was " << smallest << endl;
    cout << " The largest number you entered was " << largest << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not initializing largest and smallest to a default value

Comment: Write `if (number == -99) break;` after `cin >> number;`

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy - `number` is no initialized either.

Comment: Initiaize your variables before reading them.

Comment: This is a case where I'd break the Don't Repeat Yourself guideline because I think it would result in cleaner code: `cin >> number; while (number != -99) { /*logic goes here*/ cin >> number;  }`

Answer (score 1):

Check the number immediately after reading it, and break out of the loop then, instead of using it to update `smallest` and `largest`.

You also need to initialize `smallest` and `largest` before you can compare them with new numbers. I've done that below by treating the first iteration of the loop specially (with the `first_time` variable).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Initialize integers for use
    long int number, largest, smallest;
    bool first_time = true;

    // Set condition for user input 
    while (true)
    {
        // Allow user to input numbers to test 
        cout << " Enter a number to find the smallest and largest integer. " << endl;
        cout << " Enter -99 to quit " << endl;
        cin >> number;

        if (number == -99) {
            break;
        }

        // Evaluate user input 
        if (first_time) {
            smallest = largest = number;
            first_time = false;
        } else if (number < smallest) 
        {
            smallest = number;
        } else if (number > largest)
        {
            largest = number;
        }

    }

    if (!first_time) {
        cout << " The smallest number you entered was " << smallest << endl;
        cout << " The largest number you entered was " << largest << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check out what that does when the user enters the string "forty-two".

Comment: @JiveDadson There are plenty of other questions about validating input, I'm not going to complicate this with that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool isInitialised = false;
    //Initialize integers for use
    long int number, largest, smallest;

    // Set condition for user input 
    while (true)
    {
        // Allow user to input numbers to test 
        cout << " Enter a number to find the smallest and largest integer. " << endl;
        cout << " Enter -99 to quit " << endl;
        cin >> number;
        // if number is -99, break loop
        if (number == -99) {
            break;
        }

        // Evaluate user input 
        if (!isInitialised) {
            isInitialised = true;
            smallest = number;
            largest = number;
            // after first input no need to make comparisons.
            continue;
        } 

        if (number < smallest) 
        {
            smallest = number;
        }
        else if (number > largest)
        {
            largest = number;
        }

    }

    cout << " The smallest number you entered was " << smallest << endl;
    cout << " The largest number you entered was " << largest << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check out what that does when the user enters the string "forty-two".

Comment: @JiveDadson invalid inputs are not handled. Answer using same code posted in question and updated for required things.

Answer (score 0):

It's surprisingly tricky to get right.

SPOILER ALERT and WARNING...

If you read this before finishing the assignment, you will not suffer the pain and humiliation that the instructor wants you to. And he/she will know it's not your work. (I just thought of a way to make it look even slicker, but this is slick enough for now.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std; // Forgive me, for I have sinned.
using int_t = long int;

int_t get_number(int_t &number, int_t &largest, int_t &smallest) {
    cout << " >";
    while (!(cin >> number)) {
        cout << "Try again." << endl;
        cout << "> ";
        cin.clear(); cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    }
    smallest = min(smallest, number);
    largest = max(largest, number);
    return number;
} 
int main()
{
    cout << " Enter numbers to find the smallest and largest integer. " << endl;
    cout << " Enter -99 to quit " << endl;

    int_t largest = numeric_limits<int_t>().min();
    int_t smallest = numeric_limits<int_t>().max();
    int_t number = get_number(number, largest, smallest);

    while(-99 != number) {
        number = get_number(number, largest, smallest);
    }

    cout << " The smallest number you entered was " << smallest << endl;
    cout << " The largest number you entered was " << largest << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're facing the problem because when the user inputs -99, you're storing that in `smallest` as well. Try the code below which only overwrites the number if it is smaller **AND** if it is not -99

```
    // Evaluate user input 
    if (number < smallest && number != -99)
    {
        smallest = number;

    }
```